# Use firebase-core or play-services-analytics for adding Google Analytics in android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Do I have to add both dependencies for adding Google Analytics in my android app?

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3

Currently, I am only using `play-services-analytics` and firebase analytics is working perfectly fine for me.

Because as they both are used for integrating Google Analytics?

**Edit**

As currently I am not using firebase-core, then how can in firebase dashboard I can see active users and every data? Is it getting it from `play-services-analytics` or what? Is it because I am using crashlytics and firebase-perf?

Comment: firebase-core should work follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/

Comment: @Shishram As currently I am not using firebase-core, then how can in firebase dashboard I can see active users and every data? Is it getting it from play-services-analytics or what?

Answer (score 1):

> Because as they both are used for integrating Google Analytics ?

For using Google Analytics, you'll only need this:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3
```

And `google-services`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

**This :**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

Isn't necessary since ***you're not using nor trying Firebase*** in this case.

**Read:** https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: As currently I am not using firebase-core, then how can in firebase dashboard I can see active users and every data? Is it getting it from play-services-analytics or what?

Comment: Also I want to add both of them.

Comment: I don't think `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` would track your users in this case since Firebase has different dependency for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ Perhaps, your app was was registered for the crashlytics before.

Comment: my app is not using firebase-core, but i am using crashlytics, firebase-perf.

Comment: This is may be a dumb question, but does google play services need to be installed on the device in order to use firebase analytics? I'm trying to setup it up on a 3rd party enterprise android tablet (Elo Touch) but these tablets do not support google play services, or so I was told by tech support.